# DocuSign SIGNING_GROUP_INVALID with Certified Delivery

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I already use DocuSign API.

When I create an envelope, I usually send it to 2 recipients: 1 signer (with embedded authentication) and 1 certified delivery.

But now I would like to use a signing group as the certified delivery.

I use the **DocuSign.eSign.dll** NuGet package. My code is something like this:

```
public async Task CreateEnvelopeAsync(ContractRequest contract, Dictionary<string, string> customFields)
    {
        //do stuff...
        var envelope = new EnvelopeDefinition
        {
            EmailSubject = name,
            Status = "sent",
            Documents = new List<Document>
            {
                new Document
                {
                    Name = $"{name}.pdf",
                    DocumentBase64 = contract.DocumentBase64,
                    DocumentId = "1"
                }
            },
            Recipients = new Recipients
            {
                Signers = new List<Signer>(),
                CertifiedDeliveries = new List<CertifiedDelivery>()
            },
            CustomFields = new CustomFields { TextCustomFields = new List<TextCustomField>() }
        };

        //do more stuff...
        var signer = CreateSigner(recipient, recipientId);
        envelope.Recipients.Signers.Add(signer);
        var reviewer = CreateReviewer(recipientId, recipient, "174339");
        envelope.Recipients.CertifiedDeliveries.Add(reviewer);
        //do even more stuff...

        var envelopeSummary = await _EnvelopesApi.CreateEnvelopeAsync(_AccountId, envelope).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

static CertifiedDelivery CreateReviewer(int recipientId, Recipient recipient, int signingGroupId)
    {
        return new CertifiedDelivery
        {
            RecipientId = $"{recipientId}",
            RoutingOrder = $"{recipient.SignOrder}",
            SigningGroupId = $"{signingGroupId}"
        };
    }
```

But I get the following error:

> Error calling CreateEnvelope: {\r\n  \"errorCode\":
>   \"SIGNING_GROUP_INVALID\",\r\n  \"message\": \"Invalid signing group
>   supplied. Invalid group for the account\"\r\n}

So, I have 3 questions:

1) Is it possible to send a signing group as a certified delivery?
2) If the previous is possible, is it also possible to send a signing group as a certified delivery if I am already sending a signer with embeded authentication?
3) If both are possible, then what am I doing wrong?

The signing group id that I'm passing really exists:
[image: screenshot]